# What did Cody Fern mean when he said that Ayn Rand inspired his character and acting?

Tags: character, acting, american-horror-story

Cody Fern was asked how he prepared for playing the role of the Son of Satan in *American Horror Story*. The actor replied:

> I read a lot of Ayn Rand and I read a lot of old testament...

source:

What is the connection between Ayn Rand's use of objectivism, Satanism in *American Horror Story: Apocalypse*, and Fern's style of acting the character?

Comment: Rationalising egoism which is tied to being Satanist.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY why? where is conection

Comment: In pope talking about Satan tricking people into being egoistic. In LaVaye Satanism being described as "a rational ideology of egoistic hedonism and self-preservation" where the key are "rational ideology"

Comment: At what point of this 5 and a half minute clip is that quote said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is made by pope talking about Satan tricking people into being egoistical. In LaVaye Satanism is being described as "a rational ideology of egoistic hedonism and self-preservation" where the key are "rational ideology".